# I can't use declared TextView

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

```
public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
}
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.demo1);
textview.setText("hi");
```

It won't recognize textView, then I can't use its methods so I can't continue. What can possibly be happening?

layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/demo1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is out of `onCreate()` thus it can't recognize, put it in `onCreate()`

```
public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.demo1);
    textview.setText("hi"); 

}
```

Comment: God damn it! Sorry about that, I was trying to find what the hell was wrong for 20 minutes. Thanks

Comment: it is nothing, that can happen :)